# How can I minimize Applications in Android?

Tags: applications

In Android, is it possible to Minimize applications and continue using them again from the same point?

When I press the middle button, the application closes, I see the application as "Running" in the Task Manager but when I open the application again, it does not resumes from the same point. I have tried this for various applications.

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using?

Comment: I believe that is dependent on the way the app has been coded. Some apps close regardless of whether you press the back button or the hooe button.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Pressing the Middle (or Home) Button does "minimize" the App. This is a design idea of Android.**

If the App does not get resumed at the same point, then that is the failure of the App's developer and source code not using the relevant API calls or a general flaw in the App's code.

Comment: Just to add a side note that Android's memory management is designed to automatically terminate "minimized" apps that have not been accessed in a while when memory is needed for newly launched apps.  On lower-end phones with limited memory this may explain why background apps get terminated more aggressively.

Answer (score 1):

You can minimize the apps or actually have it as a popup:

1. Tap your home multi-screen window
2. Touch and hold the app you want to minimize
3. You can open "Option" menu on the top of the page and drag and drop, minimize, go full screen, or close the app here

This feature is not applicable to all apps. And only the newer Android versions have this feature.

Answer (score -1):

Not daft at all. You can't "minimize" an app in android, but you can leave it running in the background. If you are on a web page, hit the home button and do whatever else it is you need to do, then long press the home button and the last 6-8 apps you've used show up in a pop up, click your browser and you should be back to your web page.